# Can I template this to avoid rewriting the class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, generics

I've got a class that's rewritten for certain special cases, but I was wondering if it's possible to use C++ generic programming to decide what a function contains:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>


void printString(const std::string& str) { std::cout << str.c_str() << '\n'; }

template <typename T_callable>
struct FuncResultToString
{
    FuncResultToString(T_callable func) : call(func) {}
    T_callable call;

    void turnFuncResultToString()
    {
        std::string str = "Type: ";
        str += typeid(decltype(call())).name();
        str += " / Value: ";

        // IF RETURN TYPE IS CHAR* OR STRING
        str += call();
        // ELSE WILL HAVE TO TURN TO STRING FIRST
        str += std::to_string(call());

        printString(str);
    }
};


double afunction() { return double(5.0); }

int main()
{
    FuncResultToString<decltype(&afunction)> foo1(afunction);
    foo1.turnFuncResultToString();

    auto lambda = []() { return int(7); };
    FuncResultToString<decltype(lambda)> foo2(lambda);
    foo2.turnFuncResultToString();
}
```

This prints out:

```
Type: double / Value: 5.000000
Type: int / Value: 7
```

Which is fine for many types, but in the case the callable returns a char pointer or std::string I don't want to call std::to_string(), I just want to use the value as is. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: I would use a specialisation on the template parameter `T_callable` or `std::enable_if` using two different methods. But `nwp` below has a much cleaner solution :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can have overload:

```
const char* my_to_string(const char* s) { return s; }
const std::string& my_to_string(const std::string& s) { return s; }

template <typename T> std::string my_to_string(const T& s) { return std::to_string(s); }
```

And then:

```
void turnFuncResultToString()
{
    std::string str = "Type: ";
    str += typeid(decltype(call())).name();
    str += " / Value: ";
    str += my_to_string(call());

    printString(str);
}
```

Comment: That's a clever trick. Is there a way to change what's compiled in the function? I've thought of constexpr if and std::conditional, I'm not sure if they would work. Does C++ templates allow you to do stuff like this in a function?

Comment: In C++17, you have `if constexpr`. there are some implementations to mimic the behavior (at least in C++14 with generic lambda).

Comment: **NEVER** do this: `const std::string& my_to_string(const std::string& s)`. Consider what happens here: `const auto& x = my_to_string(std::string("abc"));`

Comment: @RustyX: It would take `const char*` overload :-) But indeed, without that overload, it would be dangling pointer. The extra copy to avoid that might be undesirable in some cases.

Comment: @RustyX is correct. You *can* use `std::string& my_to_string(std::string &); std::string&& my_to_string(std::string &&);`

Comment: @Caleth: How to handle const object then ? (and returning `&&` leads to same dangling pointer problem Btw).

Comment: @RustyX Just add `std::string my_to_string(std::string&& s){return std::move(s);}`, and shoot anyone who creates a const prvalue.

Answer (score 4):

The naive solution would be

```
void turnFuncResultToString()
{
    std::cout << "Type: ";
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(call())).name();
    std::cout << " / Value: ";

    std::cout << call();
}
```

If you need the string itself you can use a `std::stringstream ss;` instead of `std::cout` and then `printString(ss.str());`.

Comment: It's strange, I thought cout << operator would definitely have an overload for std::string, but it turns out it doesn't. That's why I had to do .c_str()

Comment: @Zebrafish [`std::string` adds one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) and [`std::string s{"Hi"}; std::cout << s;` compiles just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94de5f72f43f5703). Remove the `.c_str()` from your `printString` function and show the error message please.

Comment: @Zebrafish: There is overload for `std::basic_string` (and so for `std::string`).

Comment: @nwp oops, at the time I had forgotten to include the <string> header. When I checked the docs I looked up the ostream class and I didn't see it. The << operator for ostream takes ios&, ios_base& and streambuf only. So it's a global operator overload or part of the string class?

Comment: @Zebrafish It is a global function. Looks something like `std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const std::string &s);` normally, but because `std::ostream` and `std::string` are templates you get to see the declaration as linked above. If you ever find something that should be printable but isn't you can just add the overload yourself.